# TypeError when calling requests_oauthlib multiple times (error actually raised within urllib3)

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm writing a script to pull some data from the Twitter API. It's use of OAuth 1.1 means I'm using the `requests_oauthlib` helper library on top of `requests` to authenticate the session.

The first call to the API works, but then subsequent calls give a `TypeError` as follows:

```
/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kw)
124
125         # Superclass also sets self.source_address in Python 2.7+.
--> 126         _HTTPConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
127
128     def _new_conn(self):

TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with HTTPConnection instance as first argument (got VerifiedHTTPSConnection instance instead)
```

Looks like there's something persisting in the session as it's always on repeated use that the error comes. I've tried a clean virtualenv with latest versions installed via pip and no difference.

I'm using the context manager approach so thought that the session would be destroyed after each call, preventing this from happening:

```
with ro.OAuth1Session(**self._auth) as s:
    response = s.get(url)
```

Any fix or pointers to understand what's causing the problem would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I've tried a different approach, using the alternative way of building a session as described on the `requests` docs (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) but same error is raised.

**Edit:** Full stack in case it's useful:

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in get(self, url, **kwargs)
        485
        486         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    --> 487         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
        488
        489     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

```
/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    473         }
    474         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 475         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    476
    477         return resp

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    583
    584         # Send the request
--> 585         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    586
    587         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    401                     decode_content=False,
    402                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 403                     timeout=timeout
    404                 )
    405

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.pyc in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, **response_kw)
    564             # Request a connection from the queue.
    565             timeout_obj = self._get_timeout(timeout)
--> 566             conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
    567
    568             conn.timeout = timeout_obj.connect_timeout

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.pyc in _get_conn(self, timeout)
    254                 conn = None
    255
--> 256         return conn or self._new_conn()
    257
    258     def _put_conn(self, conn):

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.pyc in _new_conn(self)
    800         conn = self.ConnectionCls(host=actual_host, port=actual_port,
    801                                   timeout=self.timeout.connect_timeout,
--> 802                                   strict=self.strict, **self.conn_kw)
    803
    804         return self._prepare_conn(conn)

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file, strict, timeout, **kw)
    208
    209         HTTPConnection.__init__(self, host, port, strict=strict,
--> 210                                 timeout=timeout, **kw)
    211
    212         self.key_file = key_file

/Users/phil/code/Virtualenv/req_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kw)
    124
    125         # Superclass also sets self.source_address in Python 2.7+.
--> 126         _HTTPConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    127
    128     def _new_conn(self):

TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with HTTPConnection instance as first argument (got VerifiedHTTPSConnection instance instead)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Also added reference to reloading container library within IPython / Jupyter.

After a fair bit of reading, it appears the problem may arise when you call `get` on a request but don't access the body of the response (which is what I did whilst building / debugging the flow):

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#keep-alive

```
"Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data has been read; be sure to either set stream to False or read the content property of the Response object."
```

So the answer is to make sure the first thing you do after making a request is flush the response by calling `Response.content`, `Response.json()` or similar method.

The problem has only arisen when using the `requests_oauthlib` library because the session it uses is less common. I've done similar with the Facebook and LinkedIn APIs without issue, by using query parameters that don't affect the session object itself.

It also arose most often when reloading the helper library within IPython / Jupyter. Quitting the notebook or command line session then restarting would remove the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The format for OAuth1Session is:

```
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key,
                      client_secret=client_secret,
                      resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                      resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                      verifier=verifier)
```

** is used with keyword arguments, and OAuth1Session has different signature

Comment: Thanks, although that doesn't fix it. I've tried the explicit version as per your suggestion and same result. It's not the invocation, as it does work on the first use in interactive mode. The problem is the second time it's called, so not a problem with the way the method is called.